# Setting up WordPress multisite with multiple domains and subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress, reverse-proxy, multisite

My company (Co1) currently has a WordPress blog, and we recently formed a subsidiary (Co2), for which we also want a blog. We want Co2's blog to have the the basic layout and style of Co1's blog, but have its own unique copy, posts, and users, as well as some of its own CSS to match Co2's branding.

Co1's blog is hosted at `www.co1.com/blog/`, which points to a Kinsta-hosted WP instance. The root of that domain (`www.co1.com/`), the marketing website, is *not* hosted at Kinsta. The config for that is in the CDN.

We want the same type of configuration for Co2 -- root of the `www` subdomain points to a non-WP, non-Kinsta marketing website, and `/blog` subdirectory points to the Kinsta-hosted WP site.

From speaking with people more familiar than I am with WP, I think that we want to use multisite. We've explored continuing to use Kinsta to do this, but found out that Kinsta doesn't allow reverse proxies for multisite installations, which was necessary to get the subdirectory working back when this wasn't multisite and it just Co1.

Any help understanding the correct way to approach/configure this would be much appreciated. We aren't opposed to moving away from Kinsta if need be, but it would obviously be easier to stay on it if possible.